# Simple integration of a differential along 3 separate paths

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I have $$dw = \frac{y}{a}dx + \frac{x}{a}dy$$ 
and points
$$A=(0,0), B=(1,0), C=(1,1), D=(0,1)$$
How do I integrate along paths ABC and ADC? and how can I change variables integrate along the straight line AC?

What I did was
$$w =\int_0^1  \frac{y}{a}dx + \int_0^1  \frac{x}{a}dy=\frac{x+y}{a}$$
and then $x=y=1 => 2/a$
This is the same for paths ABC and ADC as I would expect.

For path AC I just let x=y and then change the limit 1 to $\sqrt{2}$ which makes sense to me and gives the same answer, but if I have x=y and they both equal 1, shouldn't it stay as 1?

Lastly how would one integrate something like $dw=xdy$ along the same paths when there isn't a dx?

It's been awhile since I've done this stuff, but what I did doesn't feel correct.

Comment: I showed you a simple solution for horizontal and vertical lines. More generally speaking, you want to write a parametrization for each of the smooth pieces of the path you are integrating over.

Comment: For AC, if you are using $x=y$ (which is fine), note that your $x$ (or $y$) ranges from $0$ to $1$, not $0$ to $\sqrt{2}$!

Comment: Check line integrals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show you how to properly compute the integral for one of the paths. See if you can do the rest, and let me know if you need further help.

First of all, if you want to integrate along a piece-wise smooth curve, it makes sense to break up the curve into parts.

If you want to integrate along $ABC$, it makes sense to break up the integral into pieces along $AB$ and $BC$.

Let's look at the integral along $AB$. $A = (0,0)$ and $B = (1,0)$.

Along the line segment $AB$, you have $y = 0$ and $x$ varies from $0$ to $1$.

(I suggest drawing a diagram on the $xy$-plane as you read along this solution.)

What does this say about your differential?

Well, $y = 0$, and so $dy = 0$. Therefore,

$dw = 0 dx + x 0 = 0$.

The integral of $dw$ along $AB$ is therefore $0.$

What about the integral along $BC$? (I hid this part under a spoiler tag. See if you can work it out on your own.)

> Along the line segment $BC$, you have $x = 1$ and $y$ varies from $0$ to $1$.
>  $dw = y 0 + \dfrac{1}{a} dy = \dfrac{1}{a}dy$
>  $\displaystyle\int_{BC} dw = \int_0^1 \dfrac{1}{a}dy = \left.\dfrac{1}{a}y\ \right|_0^1 = \dfrac{1}{a}1 - 0 = \dfrac{1}{a}.$

Since the integral $\int_{ABC} dw = \int_{AB} dw + \int_{BC} dw$, we have:

> $\displaystyle\int_{ABC} dw = \int_{AB} dw + \int_{BC} dw = 0 + \dfrac{1}{a} = \dfrac{1}{a}$.